# javascript function call on input button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a `<input type="button">` which calls my `javascript` function  `onclick`. Webpage is deployed on server and works absolutely fine when I open the webpage in chrome but throws `"The value of the property 'getValues' is null or undefined, not a Function object"` error in IE.

When I open the webpage localhost from server; there is no such error.

Here is the way I implemented.

```
<td id="abc">
    <input style="min-width:50px; min-height:25px;" value="ABC"  type="button" id="btn_abc" onclick="getValues(this); showSiteName(this)" />
    <font size="5"></font>
</td>
```

Java script function call:

```
function getValues(siteID) 
{
    status = 0;
    var site = siteID.value; 
}
```

The site value is send to my action method  in my controller.

I can not figure out the issue... Can any one please help me...

Comment: you may need to put this.value , instead of only this this

Comment: the code and html that you showed cannot produce this error. Try creating a working example that demonstrates the problem by editing your question and using "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" button.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

It is unclear as to why would you want the Value of the button which is going to be static (unless you are changing it at runtime.)

If you need this static value

> Value="ABC"

Why not give this value to the id

> id="ABC" or, id="btn_ABC"

You can then have the function as:

> onClick="getValues(this.id);"

Then you can have the js function as:

```js
function getValues(id){
  var btnValue = id
 }
//Or if you have the id as btn_ABC, You can do 

   function getValues(id){
  var temp = id.split('_');
  var btnValue = temp[1];
 }
```

Comment: I am trying to send the element and my jQuery would get the Id. If missing this.id is the problem then how it works in localhost and not when using server url.

Comment: You mean showSiteName(); function ? What are you doing with this function?

Comment: I need to use the button value not the id in my code since i am constructing a string to point to a location in my server to get the data. i need to have read button value. The error i am getting is for getValues()